# how to filter image based on RGB ratio of pixels?

Tags: python

How to create colour filter based on RGB ratio of pixels in an image using python?

I am a beginner in python and have some problems in creating colour filtering for my image.

I am trying to detect blue objects in an RGB image using opencv (python).
I could filter most of the blue objects in image but my codes couldn't filter blue objects with low intensity; my code:

```
#b=img1[:,:,0]
#img1[:,:,1]=0
#img1[:,:,2]=0
#b[b<220]=0
```

there are some pixels out of ROI that have higher intensity resulted from light scattering; so when I decrease threshold to keep low intensity pixels in ROI, many other unwanted pixels with higher intensity remain in my output image.
So, I am trying to work with RGB ratios of those pixels but my codes are not working! I appreciate any help in this regard.Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img1 =cv2.imread('IMG_1217.jpg',1)
img11=cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
b=img11[:,:,0]
r=img11[:,:,1]
g=img11[:,:,2]
a=np.divide(b,g)
c=np.divide(b,r)
a[a>1.9]=1
c[c>1.3]=1
img11=cv2.merge([b,a,c])
cv2.imshow('img11',img11)
```

Comment: I cannot share the image but those are scattered pixels. Thanks for picking my mistake on wrong ordering of channels.